# How can I select L neighbors

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'd like to know how to select the optimal L neighbors of a specific point. Like saying I need to select the 5 neighbors. Is there any parameter to change.

I want to let it select L points where : L = SQRT[number of points in data set]

I have a huge data set, so I might find a lot of points near to each others while others far from them.

> L, the number of neighbors to consider, can be chosen arbitrarily, or
>   with cross validation. With more training data, L can be larger, since
>   the training data is more dense in the underlying space X. With more
>   discontinuous or nonlinear dynamics in the classification, K should be
>   smaller, to capture these more local fluctuations.

```
 NearestNeighbors(algorithm='auto', leaf_size=30, n_neighbors=5, p=2,
             radius=1.0, warn_on_equidistant=True)
```

Comment: Your code cannot work like this. Please add square brackets around the tuple of lists to make it a list of lists, which is passed to `np.array`. Further, please make your question more precise and tell us what you have tried and what went wrong.

Comment: "I'd like to know how to select the optimal L neighbors of a specific point. Like saying I need to select the 5 neighbors. Is there any parameter to change."

Comment: Why are you giving an example which a) doesn't work and b) doesn't represent the problem you are trying to solve. What have you tried so far, and where is the problem?

Comment: I wanna use Sklearn NearestNeighbors() so how can I tell make NearestNeighbors select only first L neighbors (for example 5 first neighbors) ? it's a simple question if someone is experienced with Scikit

Comment: The `NearestNeighbors` object is constructed to do precisely that (and finding data points within a radius). Which is why I am confused as to  where the problem is. Please try to run the code provided in my answer and see if it works. Then use it on your data and see if this creates problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to let it select L points where : L = SQRT[number of points in data set]

That's not possible unless you compute the number of samples and its square root yourself. You can only pass an integer as `n_neighbors`.

The only way to take a variable number of neighbors into account is to use `RadiusNeighbors{Classifier,Regressor}`, which take a distance cutoff instead of a *k* parameter.

Comment: Simple and Great answer.

Comment: Great answer which led to my understanding of the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following example:

```
 import numpy as np
 rng = np.random.RandomState(42)
 from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors
 nnbrs = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=5)
 points = rng.randn(500, 3)
 nnbrs.fit(points)

 point_of_interest = np.array([0, 1, 0])
 distances, neighbor_indices = nnbrs.kneighbors(point_of_interest)
 neighbors = points[neighbor_indices]
```

Does this obtain the desired result? You should try this on your sparse matrix data and play with `algorithm=` (see docs), if there are calculation time / memory problems